# How to automatic selected value Select Option with Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I have two API requests.

While one of them brings the whole list of designers, one brings the information of the relevant collection.

I want that the list of the Designer ID that comes in the relevant collection matches the list that I have given in the relevant Select Element and add automatic select operation.

Please help me :) Sorry for Bad English.

My Select Element..

```
<select class="form-control mt-2" v-model="designerSelected" id="designerBox">
      <option
      v-for="designer in designerArray"
      :key="designer.designer_id"
      :value="designer.designer_id"
    >
      {{ designer.designer_firstname + " " + designer.designer_lastname }}. 
     </option>
</select>
```

My Collection API

```
axios
  .get("XXXXXXX")
  .then(response => {
    this.name = response.data[0].XX
    this.short = response.data[0].XX
    this.singleImage = response.data[0].XX
    this.textEditor = response.data[0].XX
    this.designerSelected = response.data[0].collection_designer; ( Come Designer ID )
  })
  .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
  })
```

My Designers API

```
runDesignerAPI() {
      axios
        .get("XXXXXXXXX")
        .then(response => {
          this.designerArray = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match `:value` with the same type of `v-model`:

```
<select class="form-control mt-2" v-model="designerSelected" id="designerBox">
      <option
        v-for="designer in designerArray"
        :key="designer.designer_id"
        :value="designer"
      >
        {{ designer.designer_firstname + " " + designer.designer_lastname }}. 
     </option>
</select>
```

https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select-1